# How to repruduce IE hack in jade templating (pug, now, really pug?)

Tags: html, node.js, pug

I have these two pieces of html, and I'd like to know the jade needed to produce them:

```
<body>
  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
  <table width="540" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td>
  <![endif]-->

  <table class="content" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="font-family: sans-serif; width: 100%; max-width: 540px; background: #ffffff;">
    <tr>
    <td>
```

And

```
  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <![endif]-->
```

Can't seem to convert or predict or use :verbatim well enough. Any ideas?

Comment: There's really no need to check version greater than IE9 since IE10 no longer supports conditional comments

Answer (score 1):

Convertors can help you with that.

html2jade.org is your resource for this particular issue.

Here's your code output:

```
html
  body
    //if (gte mso 9)|(IE)
      table(width='540', align='center', cellpadding='0', cellspacing='0', border='0')
        tr
          td
    table.content(align='center', cellpadding='0', cellspacing='0', border='0', style='font-family: sans-serif; width: 100%; max-width: 540px; background: #ffffff;')
      tr
        td
```

and

```
          //if (gte mso 9)|(IE)
```

Comment: I used that site. The issue is, if you try converting back, you get a different html than the original.

Answer (score 1):

This solution: `!= "<!--[if IE]><script src=\"//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js\"></script><![endif]-->"`

compile to: `<!--[if IE]><script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->`
or

```
!= "<!--[if IE]>"
your code here
!= "\n"
!= "<![endif]-->"
```